# Convert an integer to a binary string?

Tags: c++

I have to convert an integer (from 0 to 225) to an 8 char binary string, I have been trying to use bitset but I'm not having any luck. How can I intake an integer and convert it to an 8 char binary string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Write a loop that gets each bit from the integer, and then adds the character `'0'` or `'1'` to the string depending on the value of the bit.

Comment: Search a little harder, this has been asked, and answered, at least half a dozen times just counting StackOverflow.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: I ended up using a while loop instead, thanks                                                           while(val!=0) 
    { s = (val%2==0 ? "0":"1") + s; val/=2;}

Answer (score 2):

You are on a good way using `bitset`, I think. Don't know which issues you had with `bitset`, but try the following. Note that a bitset can be initialized with various types of values, one being integral type:

```
int main() {
    int value = 201;
    std::bitset<8> bs(value);
    cout << bs.to_string();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do without `bitset`, just as an alternate solution:

```
std::string ucharToBitString(unsigned char x)
{
    std::string s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        s += (x & 128) ? "1" : "0" ;
        x <<= 1;
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Edit:** As per the comment, this handles the most significant bit first.

Comment: You might want to indicate whether this is Most Significant Bit first or Least Significant Bit first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up using a while loop!